# Multiple javascript image carousels - independent controls and automatic movement

Tags: javascript, scope, slider, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have attempted to find an answer to my question here on Stack Overflow but have been unsuccessful in finding one.

As part of my JavaScript learning I am trying to create my own carousel slider. The problem is I am trying to allow for X number of sliders on the same page, each with their own automatic timers and controls. This is proving to be an issue when I try to control either one of them. For instance if I manually control one of them, the other one then stops playing as the **paused** variable is set to *true*.

I'm pretty sure that my issue is either the scope of the variables or not being more specific with targeting the slider elements (e). I may have been looking at this too long and have somewhat lost perspective on it. I would appreciate any advice with this or even just a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider-1" class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="slider ">
        <div class="slide-wrap" data-slide="0">
            <div class="slider-slide" style="background-image: url(image1.png)">
                <div class="slide-text text-background">
                    <a href="#">Slide 1</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-wrap" data-slide="1">
            <div class="slider-slide" style="background-image: url(image2.png)">
                <div class="slide-text text-background">
                    <a href="#">Slide 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-wrap current-slide" data-slide="2">
            <div class="slider-slide" style="background-image: url(image3.png)">
                <div class="slide-text text-background">
                    <a href="#">Slide 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Setup variables
let helpers = require('./helpers.js')
let sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrap')
let paused = false

//Get all sliders on page and start slider function
for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
  let slideIndex = 0
  let e = sliders[i]
  slider(e, slideIndex)
  autoChange(e, slideIndex)
}

// Slider function which adds indicator click listeners
function slider (e, slideIndex) {
  let element = e
  let interval
  let indicators = e.getElementsByClassName('slide-indicator')
  for (var i = 0; i < indicators.length; i++) {
    indicators[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      let slideIndex = Number(e.target.dataset.slide)
      paused = true
      if (helpers.hasClass(e.target, 'current') === false) {
        clearTimeout(interval)
        sliderChange(element, slideIndex)
      }
    })
  }
}

// Change slider based on index and update classes
function sliderChange (e, slideIndex) {
  let slides = e.getElementsByClassName('slide-wrap')
  let indicators = e.getElementsByClassName('slide-indicator')
  let num = slides.length - 1
  let prev = e.querySelector('.current-slide')

  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove('current-slide')
      indicators[i].classList.remove('current')
  }

  slides[slideIndex].classList.add('current-slide')
  indicators[slideIndex].classList.add('current-indicator')

  if (paused === false) {
      autoChange(e, slideIndex)
  }

}

// Automatically change slide
function autoChange (e, slideIndex) {
  let slides = e.getElementsByClassName('slide-wrap')
  let num = slides.length - 1
  if (slideIndex === num) {
    slideIndex = 0
  } else {
    slideIndex++
  }
  interval = setTimeout(function () {
    sliderChange(e, slideIndex)
  }, 3000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having paused as global variable is an issue at least. I would recommend you to create a javascript object for each slider so that each slider would have their own "paused" property.

```
let sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrap')
var sliderObjects = []
for (i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
    var slider = {slider: sliders[i], paused: false}
    sliderObjects[i] = slider
}
```

Here some useful reference on JavaScript Objects: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go and report back.

Comment: That's done it, not 100% there yet but I can tell I'm going in the right direction. Thanks again for your help.